# query ilist with linq

Tags: c#, linq, ilist

I would like to get data with linq from ilist which has type of one class - for example - iList - everything I know, that in this iList are saved emails and names, but this iList has no string type, but this class. 
How can I get them?
It would be great to put this data to my own List
Any hint how to do that?

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more information than that. For example, an actual code snippet of the `IList` and class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IList<MyNameAndEmailClass> myList = GetMyList();
var emailList = myList.Select(x => x.EmailAddress).ToList();
```

emailList will now contain only the email addresses.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
var result = list.OfType<SomeType>()
```